# How to import a discord embed from another file

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm making a discord bot that posts embeds based on commands. I have a lot of embeds and it makes my main.js very cluttered. I want to put my embeds in another file to import from, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this correctly. What am I doing wrong?

**MY EMBED CODE:** TEST.js

````
const Discord = require('discord.js')


 module.exports = (TEST) => {
          TEST(
               {
                  name: 'test1' ,
                  value: "```TESTING```",
                  inline: true,
                },
                {
                   name: 'test2' ,
                   value: "```TESTING```",
                   inline: true,
                 },
                 {
                   name:  "\u200B" ,
                   value: "\u200B" ,
                   
                 },
                 {
                   name: 'test4' ,
                   value: "```TESTING```",
                   inline: true,
                 },
                 {
                   name: 'test5' ,
                   value: "```TESTING```",
                   inline: true,
                 },
    
             )
          
    
    
          message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {})
     
       })
````

**MAIN JS CODE:**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const command = require('./command')
const config = require('./config.json')
const TEST = require('./TEST')


command(client, 'test' , (message) => {

 const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

    .setTitle('Test')
    .setColor('#C69B6D')
    .addFields(TEST)
 
 message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {})
 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are  you exporting the module as a function? You could just export it like objects and import that into the main.js

In TEST.js

Declare the TEST objects then use

```
module.exports.TEST = TEST;
```

And when you import in main.js you need to type `TEST.TEST` instead of `TEST`